# Ate raw beef patty that I microwaved for 2 mins first, Is it safe?

Tags: food-safety, beef, hamburgers, raw

I was given this Great Value brand beef patty from a person who didn't like them.

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Great-Value-100-Pure-Beef-Patties-8-lb-32-Count/10804578

I don't have a grill or stove so I decided to just microwave them. I did 1 min each side. It was brown and tasted fine.

Just want to be sure this is safe before doing it again. Also if anyone else does this, please explain your process.

Comment: Buy a thermometer. 160F, 70C is considered safe. Cooked throughout to that temp, not with a little frozen parch, as microwaves are prone to leave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cook meat products in a microwave, and be safe, but you need to make sure they're fully cooked.

Microwave ovens vary a lot in both their power output and how evenly they cook, so 2 minutes may not really be enough to be certain of cooking thoroughly. Next time I suggest you cut it in half when you think it's done, and check that the middle is both brown and very hot to touch. A thermometer would be the gold standard, but you're  not running a restaurant, you're feeding yourself with limited equipment. If in doubt, cook a little longer, and you'll know for the future. Repeat the test if you cook extra another time.

Comment: Yea it was a frozen raw beef patty so sadly I dont think the 2 mins was enough to be "very hot to touch". However, the middle seemed brown tho as I did look at it while eating. Do you think I should be fine? I know people eat raw / medium raw steak so was thinking this shouldn't be a big deal as 2 mins in a microwave should kill anything in a patty but unsure now.Will do that test next time for sure tho as I don't have a thermometer.

Comment: Even if it wasn't properly cooked, you'd need to be fairly unlucky to get ill - but don't make a habit of it!  Some burgers can look rather brown without being fully cooked, so the colour isn't enough on its own.  Steak is different, because the inside hasn't had the chance to be in contact with anything, and the outside is normally seared.  Steak tartare and burgers severed rare have to be prepared under careful conditions

Comment: thanks, I cooked another one for 4 mins(2 min on each side), it was kinda hot to the touch this time. Maybe I will try 6 mins(3 mins on each side) next time. Any issues with microwaving frozen raw beef patties for too long? I would rather be on the safe side. Taste doesn't matter to me. What microwave time is 99.9% safe?

Comment: It really depends on the microwave. All overcooking will do is make the texture change, so don't worry too much about that.